# Put Java application in background and make it read from keyboard in Linux

Tags: java, linux, input, keyboard, background-process

I have written java application that reads keyboard input and does some other work too.
How can I run that app in background and make it read keyboard input while in background in Linux?

Comment: Are you writing a keylogger in java?

Answer (score 0):

A process can only read keyboard input if its terminal/UI window/etc. has the focus. What you can do for e.g. if you have appropriate access rights on the server is to make the Java app read from a socket and send data into that socket from the keyboard.

E.g.

on a tty:

```
$ socket -sl 11555
```

on another tty:

```
$ nc 0 11555 | yourjavabinary
```

Now, whatever you type in the first tty, your Java app will receive it as input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to read keyboard events if yor java app is out of focus. You can make use of some JNI components and invoke it from you java.

Answer (score 0):

You mean background in a shell? Or background in a window manager?

For a shell you could try something with the script(1) program. It launches a new shell and captures all input and output to a file. You'd have to figure out which lines are the input though.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html